# What could have cause these scratches on my LCD?

Tags: interior, electronics

I had to remove the anti-glare coating on my LCD (using plastic polisher) because the previous owner probably used ammoniac based cleaner on it. After removing it with Novus plastic polisher, I found these micro-scratches / wear on the LCD. Tried to polish it as well, but no dice. I couldn't feel it with my nail.

Question is, have you seen similar scratches and what could have caused this? Steel wool? Screen burn caused by a buffer?

Just being curious here, because I've put a plastic anti-glare and it hides the scratches very well.

Thanks

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: The flash is killing any visibility of the scratches. Try turning I'd the flash and using a flashlight or two to light the display in a way that shows the scratches.  I would recommend lighting from the side so the light is across the scratch,  not directly at it.

Comment: Please confirm if it is an LCD screen or an LED screen. I found a site that shows fixes for LCD screens.

Comment: Lcd bmw screen. Can't really take another picture since I applied the screen protector :(

Comment: You sure you didn't cause the scratches yourself while removing the coating? It doesn't take much if the rag or whatever you used wasn't perfectly clean, hard microscopic dirt particles could scratch it.

Comment: I think it was caused by the previous owner who tried to remove the coating. I used a clean microfiber + plastic polisher, and didn't have to put too much pressure. Anyway, the plastic cover covered the whole thing, so no worries :)